# C++: Delete pointers from std::list

Tags: c++

Digging through a bunch of headers, I found these across some files:

```
Objects& objects
typedef ObjectPointers Objects;
typedef std::list<Object*> ObjectPointers;
```

So, this tells me that `objects` is really a list of pointers to Object. Is this correct?

I'm getting a memory leak and I think it is because `objects` is not being freed. Would I delete the pointers in `objects`, or delete `objects` entirely? I've tried the following, with none of them working:

```
for(auto&& child : objects) {
  delete child;
}
----------------------

delete[] objects

----------------------

objects.~Object()
```

What is the proper way to delete `objects`, and is my thought process correct about what `objects` actually is?

EDIT:

After further research, it seems like I need to delete the pointers in `objects`. So this is what I did:

```
if (!objects.empty()) {
    Objects::const_iterator it;
    for (it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); it++) {
      if (*it) {
        delete *it;  //error here
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm getting a core and it doesn't like the fact that `delete *it` is void. If `*it` was void, wouldn't the loop not run to begin with? Even if it did, I'm checking to see if `*it` exists before I try to delete it, so it shouldn't get there if it doesn't exist anyways.

Comment: To nitpick `objects` is a *reference* to a list. As for the pointers in your list, you need to think about the ownership of the objects, and whose responsibility it is to delete those objects.

Comment: Regarding the code to "delete" the list and its contents, if it really is your responsibility then the loop is the only correct option. But be sure it really is your responsibility, *and* that the pointers are pointing to dynamically created objects, as returned by `new`.

Comment: Lastly about the "leak", are you sure about it? How do you detect it? Have you used some kind of leak-detector (like e.g. [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/))?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did not use a tool to detect it, but massive core was generated (3.4GB).

Comment: Isn't a loop dangerous because you can potentially delete the pointer in the list, causing it to become rebalanced and the iteration to be undefined?

Comment: No, `delete[]` means to delete the array pointed to by the pointer, not to somehow do something to the pointer itself.

Comment: @helloworld95 The loop free's the objects the pointers are pointing at. It doesn't modify the pointer themselves. And it doesn't modify the list either. After the loop the pointers are still the same, but can't be dereferenced.

Comment: And a large core (if you get a crash) doesn't indicate a leak. If you get a core-file because of a crash, first solve the crash. Then use tools to check for leaks. Incidentally Valgrind could be used to find other memory problems as well, including many that can lead to crashes.

Comment: Assuming you know that you own the objects and are OK to delete them, don't forget that after you run through the list and delete all the objects you'll want to call objects.clear() to remove the nodes from the list.  Also, if you are getting a core dump are you sure that it's a memory leak and that the application is not crashing for some other reason.  If the application crashes then it's likely that cleanup never could happen on the list, causing it to look like a memory leak.

Comment: @Durstann i tried `objects.clear()`  after the loop, and it does not work.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's a memory leak, but I will double check with Valgrind. Even if the issue isn't a memory leak, this issue of freeing up memory would have to be addressed anyways as part of standard practice, right?

Comment: The standard practice is to not have raw pointers with ownership. Use `std::unique_ptr` unless you have reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Like Some programmer dude mentioned, `objects` is a *reference* to a `std::list` of pointers to `Object`s.

If you wanted to destroy all the elements of the list you could do so with a simple loop:

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class Object {
public:
    Object() { std::cout << "Object()\n"; }
    ~Object() { std::cout << "~Object()"; }
};

typedef std::list<Object*> ObjectPointers;
typedef ObjectPointers Objects;

int main()
{
    std::list<Object*> objects_list;
    
    objects_list.push_back(new Object());
    
    for (auto* obj: objects_list) {
        delete obj;
    }
    
    // Clear the elements from the list to avoid "use after free" issues
    objects_list.clear();
}


// This program outputs:
// Object()
// ~Object()
```

Note that `objects` in your code is not a `std::list` but a reference to one. This means that `objects` simply "points to" the `std::list`, but doesn't own it. You must ensure that `objects` isn't used after the `std::list` is destroyed to avoid issues.

Another question is: who owns the elements of the `std::list` that `object` references? If the `std::list` itself owns the elements it contains, it may be useful to consider using `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers, or even putting directly `Object` values in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Yes, I ended up doing something similar, but still running into an issue. Now, it's about the `delete(*null)` issue. As for ownership, I don't think `object` owns the elements that it references.